# React router history not render correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack to create an APP.

Everything is cool, I generate my dist files, but I upload my app on my website, like this: **my-website.com/staging/my-app**.

But when I navigate to **my-website.com/staging/my-app** it renders the error component, and If I press Home button, I see the homepage as excepted but the url in the navbar is **my-website.com/**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website doesn't located in the root url, you will need to provide a basename option

For example:

```
import createBrowserHistory from "history/lib/createBrowserHistory"
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from "react-router"

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({
  basename: "staging/my-app",
})

// component
<Router history={ browserHistory } routes={ routes } />
```

Comment: how can I achieve that?

Comment: thanks dude, seems to be working on local, but if i upload to my apache server its blank, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Did you take a look at browser console ? It must throwing some errors :)

Comment: it seems like not finding routes if i put <Route path="/staging/new" component={App}> it display, but act weird when click on the <Link>

Comment: When you set basename it means everything is relative with the basename. Do not add `/staging/` in the url

Comment: but if i click about, my url looks like my-website/staging/my-app/staging/my-app/about, whyt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108822/discussion-between-thangngoc89-and-hiero).

Comment: nevermind should be baseName: '/staging/my-app', thank you alot!